# Windows 7 a 64 bits no encuentra asadmin al instalar GlassFish

Tags: windows, glassfish

Estoy instalando Glasfish3 en un equipo Windows 7 x64.

Cuando el Wizard intenta crear un nuevo dominio retorna el error

> El Sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada

Intente ejecutar esta accion manualmente como se muestra en la guia rapida

[Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Quick Start Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/gglog/index.html)

pero al ejecutar `asadmin` me retorna el mismo error, ya lo he intentado como administrador

Comment: en qué versión de windows? deberías agregarlo.

Answer (score 1):

En el directorio

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\config
```

hay un archivo llamado `asenv.bat` abrelo con el editor de texto y elimina la linea:

```
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
```

Comment: La respuesta anterior no es del todo correcta, glassfish necesita la ruta del sdk de java, lo que debes hacer es cambiar la ruta de AS_JAVA por la ruta del sdk de tu equipo.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono no eliminando la linea set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java del archivo asenv.bat sino colocando la ruta del JDK alli ya que estaba apuntando a una ruta que no existia